# How can I change an existing column to Identity in PostgreSQL 11.1

Tags: postgresql, identity, ddl

I would like to change my existing column to Auto Identity in a Postgres Database.

I don't want to use Postgres `SEQUENCE`. I would like to use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

I tried the script below but it didn't work.

```
ALTER TABLE public.patient ALTER COLUMN patientid Type int4 
USING patientid::int4 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Following [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

```
ALTER TABLE patient 
    ALTER patientid SET NOT NULL,  -- optional
    ALTER patientid ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
        (START WITH 2);  -- optional
```

Add `NOT NULL` constraint if the column does not have the constraint yet. The optional clause `START WITH start` changes the recorded start value of the sequence.

Test it in [DB<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6ee385dfb5b9df6bd5f8b021b0d9694f)

Comment: For all PostgreSQL v11 users beware there is a bug (fixed in v12) on converting an existing serial to an identity column where PG doesn't repurpose or delete the existing sequence and throws an error for duplicate sequences on subsequent inserts. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55675778/840428 for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a table `patient` previously created as

```
CREATE TABLE patient( patientid int, col1 int );
```

and a row inserted as

```
INSERT INTO patient VALUES(1,5);
```

Firstly create a sequence starting +1 iterated from the max value of ID and make it `default` for your column

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mySeq START WITH 2;
ALTER TABLE patient ALTER COLUMN patientid SET DEFAULT nextval('mySeq');
```

and convert your column to a primary key

```
ALTER TABLE patient ALTER COLUMN patientid SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE patient ADD CONSTRAINT uk_patientid UNIQUE (patientid);
```

whenever you insert new rows such as

```
INSERT INTO patient(col1) VALUES(10);
INSERT INTO patient(col1) VALUES(15);
```

you'll observe that you sucessfully made your column as an identity column

```
SELECT * FROM patient

patientid  col1
---------  ----
1          5
2          10
3          15
```

Comment: I don't want to use postgres sequence. i would like to use ALWAYS AS IDENTITY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL to substitute the initial value of the sequence.

```
do $$
declare
id_max int4;
begin
select max(patientid)+1 into id_max from patient;
execute 'alter table patient alter patientid set not null,
                             alter patientid add generated by always as identity  (start with '||id_max||' )';
end;
$$;
```

[Test it in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G-RaBxA7)

Comment: Or `select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('the_table', 'id'), (select max(id) from the_table));`